# Why does the F-35 Lightning II have only 1 crew when the F/A-18 Hornet had 2?

Tags: crew, f-35

Many successful fighter aircraft, eg F/A-18 Hornet, have 2 crew (pilot and navigator), which (from my albeit limited research) gave great benefit in complex situations especially involving ground defences.

The F-35 Lightning II is supposed to be multi-purpose, but has only 1 crew - why?

- Do the advanced electronics compensate for the lack of a navigator?
- Would the design (aerodynamics/frame) be compromised by adding another seat?
- Something else?

Comment: I found that duplicate, but I don't think it is s dupe, because this question is specific to the JSF

Comment: @Bohemian: You should check [the answer to the linked question by KeithS](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/16303/12341). *Notice by the development of the F-15 through F-18 that designers and US top brass were already considering single-seaters to be sufficient;* - the answer extensively lists what necessitated the second crew member and which advances made them redundant. Hornet was a notch above the line, F-35 is firmly in 1-seater territory.

Comment: F/A-18A and F/A-18C are single-seat airplanes.  F/A-18B and F/A-18D are two-holers, primarily used for training.  F/A-18E and F/A-18F are significantly different airplanes, with the E being a one-holer and the F being a two-holer.  F/A-18G is an electronic warfare version of the F/A-18F.  So it is not correct that "F/A-18" is a two-seater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Why does the F-35 Lightning II have only 1 crew when the F/A-18 Hornet had 2?**

According to [program officials](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/israel-sets-sights-on-two-seater-f-35-337464/) involved in the development of the F-35, the F-35 is a single seat aircraft because:

> ***New advances in avionics and sensor fusion technology, which can 
>   allow  a single pilot to perform missions that previously required two
>   crew members*.**

- Given the fact that the F-35 is build around the concept of
  **[Network Centric Warfare](https://www.f35.com/news/detail/the-f-35-vs.-the-vhf-threat)** there is less cockpit workload for most strike missions. Consequently, the need for a co-pilot is a lot less.
- The single-seat configuration also maximizes commonality between the 
  three variants of the F-35 thereby keeping development costs low.
- The survivability of the F-35 includes limiting the probability of   detection. Ergo, a two-seater version can very easily increase the RCS of the F-35 thereby compromising its stealth capabilities

[West 2014: Joint Strike Fighter: What Do the Pilots Who Are Flying It Today Have to Say?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=9&v=Vxe4Jv1cJxI)

That said, one major drawback that remains on the one seat [design](https://ericpalmer.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/needforf35twoseatvariant2008.pdf) is the demand on one [pilot](https://www.f35.com/resources/test-pilot-tuesdays) to assimilate and decide on all the information available.